# how to pass singleton object from one page to another in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

I had created an singleton class object in page1.xaml. I need to send and access this object in page2.xaml.My code is below

```
private void Login_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       myClient credentials = Credentials_Config.CreateInstance(accesskey_Textbox.Text,secretkey_Textbox.Password);

    }
```

where Credentials_Config.CreateInstance() is the singleton class method. credentials receives the singleton object. how to pass this object to page2.xaml?can anyone help me to achieve this?.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Your backed property in Credentials_Config should be static (if it's proper singleton implementation). So just use it in any place/page of your program. You can modify CreateInstance method to return initialized instance if it exists or init it and then return.

```
public static Credentials_Config
{
    private static myClient _client;
    public static myClient CreateInstance (string key, string pass)
    {
        if (_client == null)
        {
            _client = new myClient();
            // some init stuff
        }
        return _client;
    }
}
```

If you need thread-safe singleton your must set lock while create instance of myClient.